# Escaping quotes inside quotes in bash

Tags: bash

I want to extend an existing environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` with furthe arguments which contain a quoted string:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p"
```

I've tries escaping the quotes with the backslash:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p\""
exec java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /somejar.jar "$@"
```

But this does not seem to work as I get the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Killing
```

How could I escaped quotes correctly?

This did not work either:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS "'-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p"'
```

**Update**

How I test it now.

```
printf "%s\n" abc -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p"
```

Gives just:

```
abc
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p
```

Which is expected.

All other variants tries so far give more lines:

```
string="abc"
string="$string"$" -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p\""
printf "%s\n" $string
```

Result:

```
abc
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo
Killing
the
process
because
of
the
OutOfMemoryError.;
kill
-9
%p"
```

Also tried:

```
string="abc"
string=$"$string -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p\""
printf "%s\n" $string
```

Also tried:

```
string="abc"
string="$string "'-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p"'
printf "%s\n" $string
```

With the same effect

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @melpomene I've seen this but still dont get how to fix my case.

Comment: Shouldn't you double-quote the variables while printing?

Comment: @lexicore Use an array variable. You can't do this with a single string.

Comment: @lexicore: For the cases you said it gives more lines, it should have been `printf "%s\n" "$string"`

Comment: @Inian Apparently if I get more lines with `printf "%s\n" $string` then my Java call fails. So a positive `printf "%s\n" "$string"` does not help me much.

Comment: @melpomene `JAVA_OPTS` is baked in scripts pretty well. Changing that to array isn't really an option.

Comment: @lexicore Then you can't do what you want.

Comment: @Inian Isn't the part after *Update* exactly that?

Comment: @lexicore: But still it is unclear (atleast to me) what is the exact output string you need

Comment: @Inian I need `printf "%s\n" $string` to print exactly two lines because that would mean that the second argument is not broken over spaces. It's stated around "Which is expected." line in the update.

Comment: @lexicore: not double-quoting will always make the shell do split words, you can't get around that.

Comment: @Inian Then I don't know how to test it efficiently. Without making that java call.

Comment: Your test is fine; it's just that what you're trying to do is impossible.

Comment: @melpomene Not that I don't believe you but a lot scripts I saw just concatenate `JAVA_OPTS` in some way without using arrays. I don't mean homegrown scripts but things like Apache Tomcat etc.

Comment: Yes, but they probably don't try to embed spaces into a single argument.

Answer (score 2):

First: you cannot control word splitting (i.e. how a variable's value gets split into "words") by adding quotes, escapes, or anything like that within the variable's value. When the shell parses a command line, it parses quotes and escapes before it expands variables, so by the time quotes/escapes inside the variable are part of the command, it's too late for them to have the intended effect. Net result: if the variable reference is in double-quotes, it will not be word-split at all; if it is not in double-quotes, it will be split at every whitespace character, no matter what quotes/escapes/whatever is around them.

However, *if you control how the variable is used*, you can use an array instead. You probably shouldn't call it `JAVA_OPTS`, because that's a standard name and not expected to be an array. But you can do something like this:

```
java_opts_array=(-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p")
exec java $JAVA_OPTS "${java_opts_array[@]}" -jar /somejar.jar "$@"
```

Or, roll in the JAVA_OPTS value like this:

```
java_opts_array=($JAVA_OPTS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo Killing the process because of the OutOfMemoryError.; kill -9 %p")
exec java "${java_opts_array[@]}" -jar /somejar.jar "$@"
```

Comment: But in that case you don't need a variable at all: `exec java $JAVA_OPTS -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="echo Killing ..." -jar /somejar.jar "$@"`

Comment: @melpomene True; I'm assuming the actual code is more complicated.